# Show that $\vec \varepsilon(t, \vec x) = \vec E e^{-i(\omega t - \vec k \cdot \vec x)}$ satisfies Maxwell's equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $\vec k$ be a vector in $\Bbb R^3$ and let $\omega = |\vec k|$.  Fix $\vec E \in \Bbb C^3$ with $\vec k \cdot \vec E = 0$ and $\vec k \times \vec E = i \omega \vec E$.  Show that 
>   $$\vec \varepsilon(t, \vec x) = \vec E e^{-i(\omega t - \vec k \cdot \vec x)}$$
>   satisfies $\nabla \cdot \varepsilon = 0$ and $\nabla \times \vec \varepsilon = i \frac {\partial \vec \varepsilon}{\partial t}$.

I'm trying to prove that this function satisfies the first equation.  Here's what I've got: $$\nabla \cdot \vec \varepsilon = \nabla \cdot \vec E e^{-i(\omega t - \vec k \cdot \vec x)}= \sum\vec E_j' e^{-i(\omega t - \vec k \cdot \vec x)} + \sum E_j e^{-i(\omega t - \vec k \cdot \vec x)} (i k_j)$$
This second sum is just $(\vec k \cdot \vec E) i e^{-i(\omega t - \vec k \cdot \vec x)}$ and is thus $0$.  I can't think how to prove that the first sum is zero, though.

Comment: I think what they assume is that $\vec{E}$ is the same throughout space.

Comment: $\vec E$ is constant,right? So $\vec E_j'$ is zero.

Comment: Oh. Yeah.  That makes sense.  Thanks.